# Local Area Network (LAN) Settings disabled in IE Browser

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

The Local Area Network (LAN) Settings has been disabled in the IE 11 browser as per the attached and blue coat proxy settings has enabled by default and unable to enable it through group policy or registry edit. I tried googling and also enabling multiple option in Group policy but no luck.

Also, I could find options to enable/disable "LAN Settings" button but not for enabling the options (Blue coat or proxy) inside that.

Operation System: Windows 10

IE version: Internet Explorer 11 [image: Error Screenshot]

Navigation: IE options --> Connections --> LAN Settings

Comment: Is this a business computer that is possibly on a domain and controlled by the company you work for? The goal here is to **remove** group policies so that you can change the settings you want. The message “some settings are managed” means group policies do exist that are forcing these settings. You can run `rsop.msc` to see what cumulative policies are applied and quickly identify active policies. The policies can be removed through `gpedit.msc` or by your IT admin if it’s a business computer.

Comment: From the screenshot you provided, we can see "Some setting are managed by your system administrator", 

So if our PC is a domain-joined PC, maybe this setting is controlled by the domain group policy.

So if our PC is a non-domain-joined PC,  maybe this setting is controlled by the blue coat proxy settings.